# SQL Statement Where clause not comparing varchar to Decimal value

Tags: sql-server

Table displays the output as below in SQLServer 2008

```
Sno Currency     Val1          Val2
1   PLN          309471355.4   228185914.7
2   USD          0.00000000    0.00000000
```

I need to skip the records which as 0 in value. Tried casting the Cost column but returns the error.

Pls. find below the SQL Query

```
Select 
Sum(curr) as 'Cost',
sum(val) as 'Val1'
From Table
Where
Cast('Cost' as int) >1
```

returns the error message as

> Error Msg Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Cost'
>   to data type int.

Appreciate any suggestion to filter that records.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
Cast('Cost' as int) >1
```

it tries to cast the `varchar` 'Cost' to a int. Which do not work

You need to do a sub query for summing up the value. Like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    Select 
        Sum(curr) as Cost,
        sum(val) as Val1
    From 
        Table
) AS tbl
Where
    tbl.Cost >1
```

Or you can also do it with a `HAVING` like this:

```
Select 
    Sum(curr) as Cost,
    sum(val) as Val1
From 
    Table
HAVING Sum(curr)>1
```

But what it sounds like you do not even what a sum. You just want to filer away the 0. So why don't you just do this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table where NOT table.val=0
```